# Spin-orbit interaction in the frame of the nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, electrons, spin-orbit

When I derived the spin orbit interaction, I switched to the electron's reference frame, so it feels a magnetic field $B$.
after calculations I get the spin orbit interaction in the electron's frame of reference. why does it stay the same when I go back to the nucleus frame of reference? in that frame of reference there is no magnetic field B. so why isn't the spin orbit interaction 0 in the nucleus frame of reference?

Comment: Can you articulate any of this with math?

Comment: I think, there is not much maths involved: You just consider the atom from the electron's view and get a term $H_{LS}=-\vec\mu\vec B$ in your hamiltonian where $\vec\mu$ is the electron's magnetic moment which is proportional to its spin $\vec S$, while $\vec B$ is the magnetic field at the electron's position, which is explained to be induced by the proton rotating around the electron and is proportional to the orbital angular momentum $\vec L$ which, however, is reinterpreted as the electron's angular momentum by switching back to the proton's coordinate system.